# normalizing image with torchvision and PIL produces banding (overflowing pixels)

Tags: python, image-processing, pytorch, python-imaging-library, torchvision

I am trying to "normalize" an image with `torchvision.transforms.Normalize`.

The result looks okay if displayed using OpenCV. It looks broken when displayed using PIL.

What is happening and how can I fix it?

```
#common
path = './image.png'

import torchvision.transforms as T
transform = T.Compose([
    T.ToTensor(),
    T.Normalize(mean=[0.4604, 0.4661, 0.4107], std=[0.1967, 0.1825, 0.1944]),
])
```

[image: Original image]

```
# okay:
import numpy as np
import cv2

img_cv = cv2.imread(path)
img_cv = cv2.cvtColor(img_cv, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
img_cv = np.array(transform(img_cv).permute(1,2,0))
cv2.imshow('imm', img_cv)
```

[image: normalized OpenCV image]

```
# failing:
from PIL import Image

img_pil = Image.open(path)
img_pil = transform(img_pil)

trs = T.ToPILImage()
trs(img_pil).show()
```

[image: normalized PIL image]

What transformation do I need to receive correct PIL image normalization?

Comment: I can see three JPEG images (a cat, a blue cat and a *"confused cat"*) along with some uncommented code that opens a PNG.

Comment: Above image is the original one, which is read by opencv and PIL, images below are received by applying the same normalization on read images(left one is opencv normalized, 'confused' one is PIL), I can assume that PIL reads image in alternative way, so in order to do correct normalization I need additional transformation for PIL image.

Comment: don't blame PIL. you are using torchvision. you haven't paid attention to data types (`.dtype`) and value ranges (min, max) -- I have cleaned up your question so it's easier to see what is doing what. please take the [tour] and review [ask] and [mre]

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Thank you for your kind edit, beautiful presentation is not my strong suit, however it seems something wrong with `torchvision.ToPILImage()`,
I found someone experiencing the same problem: [ https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/a-small-bug-for-torchvision-transforms/16123 ], although his solution prevents normalized image from overflowing, it gives slightly different image from normalized cv2 image

Answer (score 0):

Check your `img_pil` after transforming and see:

- its range, `np.max(img_pil)`
- shape `img_pil.shape` and
- `img_pil.dtype`